# Create and publish products with ebay API's

Tags: php

i need create and publish products in ebay with php , i find this sdk, but this not work for me, some have an code or example for this?
    https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php

in this sdk i get this error

```
Cannot read credentials from /.ebay_sdk/credentials in C:\wamp64\www\ebay\vendor\dts\ebay-sdk-php\src\Credentials\CredentialsProvider.php on line 132
```

but i changue the credentials in CredentialsProvider.php

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same SDK (and it's amazing how awesome it is). The guy who created this SDK also provides some examples. You can find them all [here](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples). In the Trading folder, you will find 6 (I think) different examples of how to list an item using this SDK.
If you still have problems with the credentials, you could add the credentials manually (but I don't recommend it). Instead of using

```
$service = new Services\TradingService([
    'credentials' => $config['sandbox']['credentials'],
    'sandbox'     => true,
    'siteId'      => $siteId
]);
```

you could use

```
$service = new Services\TradingService([
    'credentials' => [
        'devId' => 'YOUR_DEV_ID',
        'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        'certId' => 'YOUR_CERT_ID',
    ],
    'siteId'    => EBAY_SITE_ID,
    'sandbox'   => true,      // or false, up to you
    'token'     => 'YOUR_TOKEN'
]);
```